# Changing the branch on which another branch is based after changes have already been shared

Tags: git

I’m hacking on a GitHub-based project and I’m putting each new feature in a separate branch. I started from the upstream `master` branch and made some changes in a branch `feature1`. The problem is that I forgot to switch back to `master` before implementing `feature2`, so my tree looks like this:

```
* 4a0d1ef - Added feature 3 (HEAD, feature3)
| * 685534d - Finished feature 2 (feature2)
| * ef31e06 - Started feature 2
| * cd2ebe3 - Finished feature 1 (feature1)
| * dbd1041 - Started feature 1
|/  
* 9bfffc2 - Latest upstream change (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```

(I implemented a third feature, and that time I remembered to make my changes against `master`.) I have already submitted all three features as separate pull requests, so I don’t think rebasing is possible. Is there any way to change the `feature2` branch so that it’s based on `master` instead of the `feature1` branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
```

`master` is the new baseline, `feature1` is the old baseline, and `feature2` is the branch you're changing.

If your pull request has already been accepted, there's not much you can do.  Otherwise, do the rebase and do a new pull request.

Comment: Fortunately the maintainer hadn’t merged anything yet, so this was fine. Thanks!